# How to ensure a signal is high until another signal has been asserted in System Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, system-verilog-assertions

I want to check is signal 'a' is high until signal 'b' has been asserted.

signal 'a' should not become 0 before signal 'b' = 1;

How to do it using concurrent assertions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
assert property (@(posedge clk) $rose(A) |-> A throughout B[->1]);
```

Comment: If I want to generate counterexample with this condition in the trace, will just negating the property as shown below work?
`assert property (@(posedge clk) (not($rose(A) |-> A throughout B[->1]))); `